# Is it legal to mention some affiliate companies as our sponsors in website?

Tags: advertising, legal, affiliate

I have registered a few affiliate marketing companies to make some addtional money.

There are 125*125 banners are displayed in right side of the website for them. Let assume that they Bluehost, Hostgator, Semrush.

If I displayed there names with link or 125*125 image with link under **"Our Sponsors"** tag, is it legal?

Or it depends on the company?

Comment: Why would it be illegal to mention your sponsors?  Unless you have signed something with them that prohibits you from mentioning them, I don't even know why you might think it might be illegal.

Answer (score 4):

It usually depends on the country and the company's requirement/agreement for disclosing the relationship.

For example in the US, the FTC requires **clear and conspicuous disclosures for affiliate links**. You can read about these in the following guides from the FTC:

- **Dot Com Disclosures 2013 guide**:

  https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/press-releases/2013/03/ftc-staff-revises-online-advertising-disclosure-guidelines
- **What People Are Asking 2015 guide**:

  https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/ftcs-endorsement-guides-what-people-are-asking

Example of disclaimer page:

[image: Example of disclaimer page via TermsFeed]

Example of disclosure when posting on social media:

[image: Example of disclosure on social media via TermsFeed]